# Enter fractions in a uitextfield from 3 UIPickers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield, uipickerview

So what I'm intending to do is instead of typing in decimals, I want to be able to enter whole numbers and fractions in a textfield. Or select them from a UIPicker.

Example: Feet, Inches, fractions.(2 - 4 1/2).

What's the best way to accomplish this? Please be detailed in your answer. Thank you in advance!

Update: Ok maybe a little more detail is needed.

I'm going to use the picker, and want to display 5 rows like this:

```
<Ft>    <In>
0 0  S  0 0  S  1/16
1 1  P  1 1  P  1/8
2 2  A  2 2  A  3/16
3 3  C  3 3  C  1/4 
4 4  E  4 4  E  5/16 
ect...all the way to 9, and to 15/16 for the fractions. (Note the space between Ft and Inches and title for row).
```

Ok, So I was able to get 3 pickers to display on screen just how I wanted, my biggest issue is getting it to display in the textfield properly. So just how the example is above, ft has it's own picker, inches has it's own, and fractions has it's own, How would you get all three to display as "00ft 00 0/0in" in one text field? 
UPDATE: the code below is correct, make sure you create an IBOutlet for your UIView that contains the pickers, and hook it up in IB.

.m file

```
feetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int feet = 0; feet <= 9; feet ++){ 
    NSString *feetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%", feet];
    [feetArray addObject:feetString]; // Add the string.
}    

inchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int inch = 0; inch <= 12; inch ++){ 
    NSString *inchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%", inch];
    [inchArray addObject:inchString]; // Add the string.
}

fractionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int frac = 0; frac <= 15; frac ++){ 
    NSString *fractionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/16", frac];
    [fractionArray addObject:fractionString]; // Add the string.
}

}


//How many rows in each Picker.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView { 
if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    return 2;
}
if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
    return 2;
}

return 1;
}

//Selects array for each picker.
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component { 

if (pickerView.tag == 1) {

    return [feetArray count];
}
if (pickerView.tag == 2) {

    return [inchArray count];
}

return [fractionArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component { 

if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    return [feetArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
    return [inchArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
    return [fractionArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

//Formats the textfield based on the pickers.
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSString *result = [feetArray objectAtIndex:[feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ft", [feetArray objectAtIndex:[feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [inchArray objectAtIndex:[inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [inchArray objectAtIndex:[inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@in", [fractionArray objectAtIndex:[fractionPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

RiseTextField.text = result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting up `UIPickerView` object as the `inputView`, you won't need to worry about text input. Tapping on the text field would bring up the picker and make the input constrained just as you want it. You can either subclass or set them directly in your controller. I set it up as a subclass [`here`](http://pastie.org/1982220). Its a rough implementation of what you need as I understand it. You can take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: Looks like in your example you have 1 picker with 3 rows? So I don't need 3 different pickers?

Comment: Why would you want to when you can do it with one. Is there a specific reason for choosing 3?

Comment: Yeah, I was told it couldn't be done with just one. lol I knew there had to be.

Comment: honestly I like having the 3 pickers, because I get the separation look between the feet and inches, would you be able to help with the formatting with 3 pickers?

Comment: With your example getting "UIViewController may not respond to initwithframe" warning...any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your earlier request. It looks like you are sending a `initWithFrame` message to a `UIViewController`. Is there any code that you can provide so that I can look at?

Comment: it's the code you referred me to. What I'd really like to do is have two pickers really if possible, it gives the separation look to the ft and inches and I think it looks nicer. Do you know what I would have to change in order for it to work with two pickers? also, after selecting the ft, in, and frac from the picker, I think i'll need to convert to decimal to do the math, then back to fraction to display the answer. I have to code to change from dec to fraction, but not fraction to decimal.

Comment: The code doesn't message `initWithFrame` to a `UIViewController` object. It is just a `UITextField` subclass. As for the two pickers thing, it might be possible. You will have to create a container view for both the pickers and assign that container view as its `inputView`.

Comment: I have made another [`sample`](http://pastie.org/2009301) here. This shows that two pickers are possible. Modify it for your needs.

Comment: Where you have `self`, would I change that to my UITextField name?

Comment: No, this is a subclass of `UITextField`. So if you are using IB, change the class name in the `Identity Inspector` to `MyFractionField` or if you are doing this programmatically, replace all references to `UITextField` with `MyFractionField` and import the header file.

Comment: im using IB for my views. So change the class name in IB to `MyFractionField` and then I can just copy the code into my .h and .m file? Sorry I'm a little confused right now.

Comment: I have included codes for `MyFractionField.h` and `MyFractionField.m`. Include them and once you have changed the class name, it should work. This works because I have set all the setting up of the input views within the custom text field subclass.

Comment: ill give it a shot, have to restore my project. It won't run at all now.

Comment: ok, so I restored it. added you .h and .m file, I had the pickers setup from the MainViewController files. Should I delete all that? Because the pickers are showing up, but there not working correctly, and when I hit my calculate button, I get the alert I setup when nothing is in the textfield. I also set the class for the textfield to the `MyFractionField`. I noticed your `UIPickerView` are not IBOutlets, so I'm assuming your pickers are showing up pro-grammatically?

Comment: [`This`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/FractionSample.zip) is a sample project. Yes, I am creating the picker views programmatically and putting them in a composite view that becomes the text field's `inputView`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I added some code above to show how I'm setting up my pickers, perhaps it may be easier to show how I can adjust my code rather than implementing something completely different? Thanks, I really do appreciate all your help!

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I posted, Trying to figure out how to get it to work with what I have above. It works fine with one picker, but as soon as I have 2 pickers it gets a little harder to format for me.

Comment: Why don't you define a composite view which holds both the pickers and apply transforms to it?

Comment: Yeah your right, I just changed that now, but on my arrays, it displays both arrays on both pickers, and only shows 1 wheel in the textfield. I've been trying to see how you did it in your example and how to apply that to mine, but can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: Since you are using the same delegate for both the pickers, you need to identify the picker for which you are returning the data. Compare the `pickerView` argument passed to the delegate methods with your two pickers like `if ( pickerView == feetPicker ) { // return appropriately } else { // return for the inchPicker }`.

Comment: I tried doing that like you had in your example, and it would only show blank black pickers for both. `if ( pickerView == feetPicker ) { return [feetArray count]; } else { return [inchArray count]; }`So here it would only display blank black pickers...not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Hard to tell. Seems ok. Your argument seems to be `thePickerView`. Are you comparing with it?

Comment: Just updated the code above to show exactly what I have now for the pickers. Maybe that will help?

Comment: What is `feetPicker` again? It seems to be the composite view containing both the pickers as you said you had changed.

Comment: `feetPicker` is my picker for feet, then I have `inchesPicker` for inches, both pickers in the same view with a toolbar on top and a done button to dismiss the pickersView. So i have `IBOutlet UIPickerView *feetPickers` and one for inches...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you further. If you can reopen the question, please do. I will add the same bounty I was awarded.

Comment: I don't think I can reopen it. I'm sorry if I aggravated you. I'm trying to learn this stuff the best I can. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I'm going to give you the answer. Thank so much for helping me, I figure out what was wrong. On the inchArray, the set object name was wrong as you see above. Ive got all 3 pickerViews displaying just as I wanted. If you could help me with the formatting in the textfield that would be great!! I can repost what I currently have if you would like?

Comment: What're you doing now and what would you like it to be?

Comment: I posted what I have right now, the pickers display perfectly, just need to get the formatting correct in the textfield like you had in your example, and then I'm done!! If you would be so kind!!

Comment: Get `class method +stringWithFormat no found` warning on `RiseTextField.text = [NSString stringWitFormat:@"%@ %@", string1, string2];` this line.

Comment: I see why, I have 3 pickers now, so should be 3 strings...same error..but should have string3 too...not sure

Comment: Nor sure if it helps formatting, but I set feet picker to tag 1, inches = 2, and fractions = 3...?

Comment: It was a typing error. It should've been `RiseTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", string1, string2];`.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSString stringWitFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x275b18'

Comment: It's not `stringWitFormat:`, it is `stringWithFormat:`. Notice the missing `h` in the middle.

Comment: oh geez, lol. Ok, warnings are gone, Formating is still not showing correct tho, updated code above to what I currently have. I have 3 strings since I have 3 pickers.

Comment: Remove the space in `NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d ",[inchArray objectAtIndex:row]];`. So it should be `NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",[inchArray objectAtIndex:row]];`

Comment: Yeah that doesn't help...I noticed we are formatting the arrays...shouldn't we be formatting the pickers?

Comment: You are right about that. I have updated the code [`here`](http://pastie.org/2043041).

Comment: `'UIView' may not respond to '-selectedRowInComponent:'` and `passing argument 1 of 'objectAtIndex:' makes integer from pointer without a cast` I have my pickers as UIViews, that how I'm able to display all 3 within the same UIView with a toolbar. If I change my IBOutlets to `IBOutlet UIPickerView *feetPicker` ect.. the errors go away but formatting is still off. showing 9 numbers for each picker. right now I changed it back to be `IBOutlet UIView *feetPicker;` Does that help?

Comment: UIView in a toolbar? Can you send me the code? I can't help if I am given new info every time.

Comment: The whole project? Do you have an email?

Comment: You can send it to `deepakqb@gmail.com`

Comment: Ok I sent it. I noticed on my fractionArray that I forgot to change the string name to `fractionString`. The app also crashes when selecting anything above 9 on the pickers...

Comment: I've sent you a working copy. If you've further questions, open a new one.

Comment: Will do! Thank you so much, I know this was a lot of back and forth, but I really do appreciate it!!

Comment: I posted another question about getting the values of the textfield and converting all to inches so my calculation works...if you could take a look I would greatly appreciate it! [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6308022/613858]

Comment: @Deepak If I wanted to show an alert when the textfield has `00ft 00 0/16in` I can't seem to get the formatting correct...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would advice to use a picker, it's way easier then typing fractions and will prevent the input of incorrect fractions.

There are two ways to get the fractions into your UIPicker, use the [pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW1) method of your UIPicker delegate to give the fraction as a string. You can use UTF8 fraction characters like ¼ with this function.

If is not giving enough flexibility. You could make images of the fractions and put the images into the picker by using the [pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW2) method of your delegate.

The documentation will give you lots of information! Good luck!

Comment: Can you relook at my question? I have posted my code and hope this helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like the date picker with multiple wheels to choose each part of the distance. Unfortunately there isn't a way to do this. You have 2 options though. The simple option is to use several pickers next to each other. It wont look quite the same but it's simple. The more complicated option is to build one with UIScrollViews and style it to look the way you want it too.