# Retrieve UITextfField values and convert to inches with decimal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

If I have formatting for a textfield like:

```
//Formats the textfield based on the pickers.
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSString *result = [feetArray objectAtIndex:[feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ft", [feetArray objectAtIndex:[feetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [inchArray objectAtIndex:[inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [inchArray objectAtIndex:[inchesPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@in", [fractionArray objectAtIndex:[fractionPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

myTextField.text = result;
}
```

Which display's in the textfield like `00ft 00 0/16in` How can I change that all to inches with decimal? I'll need to take the ft, and multiply by 12 = variable.Then add that to inches, as well as take my fraction 1/16 and divide that by 16 to get my decimal value and then add that to the inches so it shows like 1234.0625 in order to make my calculation. Can someone help me accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString * theString = RiseTextField.text;
NSString * feetString = [theString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
NSString * inchesString = [theString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 2)];
NSUInteger rangeLength = ([theString length] == 14) ? 1 : 2;
NSString * fractionString = [theString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, rangeLength)];

double totalInInches = [feetString doubleValue] * 12 + [inchesString doubleValue] + [fractionString doubleValue] / 16;
```

Comment: Right now I'm getting the value of the textfield like this `double a = [[RiseTextField text] doubleValue];` I'm guessing I need to some how now call `totalInInchesString`??

Comment: Like this: `double a = [totalInInchesString floatValue];`?

Comment: Looks like your getting this from the pickers...Im not getting the value to display it, I want to set it to a variable...all in inches with decimal

Comment: Ok, I hooked it up to a label just to see the output, and its not displaying the decimal at all.

Comment: Edited it to get the value from `RiseTextField`.

Comment: that did it! Thank you so much!! you have been a huge help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the number that you want by doing the calculations with the numbers you have there. Once you've got the actual number, you should use a NSNumberFormatter to present it with the desired amount of decimals and format.

This should solve your problem. Or did you need help converting the strings to numbers so that you can add them together?

Comment: Well I orginally had it where I would enter decimal values in the textfield, I didnt like that, so I changed the input to Pickers so I could make the user enter only what I wanted them to instead of formatting my own keyboard. So I already have a function to convert decimal to fraction after the calculation, but now I need to convert fraction to decimal before the calculation. So I think I really need to covert everything to inches with decimal, sound correct?

Comment: Or could you give an example on NSNumberFormatter with my `00ft 00 0/16in`?